# Write log output only on stdout python

Tags: python, logging, stdout, stderr

I have the following code:

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__.replace('__',''))
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

format = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s")

streamH = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
streamH.setFormatter(format)
log.addHandler(streamH)
```

In this way the log capure both stdout and stderr, how can I have a .log file containing only the stdout?

Comment: How do you create the mentioned .log file?

Comment: just running the python file with python3 file.py > log.log

Comment: But `... > log.log` does not redirect the stderr to the file, only the stdout. (You would need to append `2>&1` to capture both). Maybe you want to replace `sys.stdout` by `sys.strderr` in the `StreamHandler` config to separate the regular output with logging output. I'm now only guessing.

Comment: Writing sys.stdout in the StreamHandler the log should write only in the stdout or not?

Comment: I suggest you edit the question to make it more clear. Make a reproducible example and show where its output differs from the expected output.